# Type 'string' has no member 'playback'

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

While trying to build a xylophone in xcode 10.1, using swift 4.2 on iOS12, i used a button to play a .wav file and entered the following code but the following error shows up:

> "type 'String' has no member 'playback'"

```
func playSound() {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "soundName", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [])
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            /* The following line is required for the player to work on iOS 11. Change the file type accordingly*/
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

            /* iOS 10 and earlier require the following line:
             player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3) */

            guard let player = player else { return }

            player.play()

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your project is setup for Swift 4.2 and not an earlier version?

Comment: If you're in swift 4, use `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` instead of `.playback` for the category.

Comment: Your code is expecting an .mp3 file but is the soundfile really a .wav file?

Comment: I tried using AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback instead of .playback. Still doesn't work. Yes I also checked the swift version its 4.2. And its got a .wav extension it has to be .wav file right? I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking around StackOverflow and I borrowed this piece of code which works, I don't know if its the conventional way of doing it though.

**Swift 4.2**

```
import AVFoundation
var player = AVAudioPlayer()

let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "note1", ofType: "wav")!)
    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        player.play()
    } catch {
        print("couldn't load file :(")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func playSound() {

    let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: selectedSoundFileName, withExtension: "wav")
    do{
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL!)
        audioPlayer.play()
    } catch {

    }
}
```

This is another variation that you might be able to try! Let me know if this format works for you. I built a xylophone app myself a long time ago inside of a Udemy course. Pretty much would be easier to put the sound files directly into your project and run them through there, than to pull them from anywhere in my opinion.

this is the most "Swifty" way I could implement this for you.

Comment: Yeah I'm doing the same udemy course now :P. Also you need to create the var audioPlayer and import AVfoundation. Other than that, your answer is the same as mine :)

Comment: Yeah I posted mine quite literally the same time you did haha sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

If you click jump to definition on `AVAudioSession` Xcode will open the raw source file for the class and from there you can view the structure of each method in the class. This is helpful for viewing the structure of each function and for determining the data parameters of each function. Additionally there are annotations above each variation of the class functions compatible for different iOS deployment targets, indicated by the `@available(iOS 11.0, *)` annotations. We're focusing on the `open func setCategory` function in this class.

Helpful information in the raw source file

```
 Allowed categories: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
 Allowed modes: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, AVAudioSessionModeMoviePlayback, AVAudioSessionModeSpokenAudio
 Allowed options: None. Options are allowed when changing the routing policy back to Default
```

I edited the category and mode parameters in my function as follows:

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
    print("Playback OK")
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    print("Session is Active")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```